# Button alignment with input field in Bootstrap 3 - chrome issue?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a searchbar with a dropdown with Bootstrap 3.
 http://www.bootply.com/8kPb2KzcKH#

The alignment of the dropdown button is slightly off with the input field and the search button. This seems to be an issue in Chrome only and seems to align nicely in Firefox and IE 9/10.

Also if I don't use large buttons, it seems to work okay
http://www.bootply.com/RBSV0EP8Oo

I want o use the large buttons. Does anyone know how to address this in Chrome?

Comment: I see that your input has a 46px height set to it from CSS and the select button doesn't. If you add that the problem is fixed. The other way round is to give the input an auto height and make the search glyphicon smaller.

Comment: @Caelea-Thank you very much for your response. Yes the input height is set by bootstrap.css (not custom css) But I do see your point, if I removed the glyphicon and just had some text in the search button, it also ends up with the same height alignment issue. I was hoping that there would be a standard way to address this but if there isn't, your solution of setting the height for the dropdown is a good one